# How to update the Aapache Solr's stopword.txt file using Php-Solr

Tags: php, solr

I am using solr in my application and want it to ignore some of search queries like "Country", "Black Friday", "Cine" etc. 
I want it to return nothing if it encounters such queries strings.

I can easily add the phrases in stopword.txt file in solr but I don't want to add it directly.
Is there any methods, functions in Php-Solr so that I can add it using Php script?

There will be a view where site Admin can add/delete the list of phrases & I'll add/remove the terms using PHP script.

Answer (score 1):

You should look into the Solr 4.8+ features of managed synonym and stopword filter factories. 
These provide a REST API for managing the content of these dictionaries.